# Removing repeats and blanks from R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologise in advance for the data structure here, but I'm stuck with it...

I have a data frame with lots of repeats and blanks, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
country=c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia"), 
survey.1=c("Influenza","", "","","Influenza","Influenza"), 
survey.2=c("","Hepatitis C","","","",""), 
survey.3=c("West Nile Virus", "", "", "", "", "West Nile Virus"))

      country  survey.1    survey.2        survey.3
1 Afghanistan Influenza             West Nile Virus
2 Afghanistan           Hepatitis C                
3     Algeria                                      
4   Australia                                      
5   Australia Influenza                            
6   Australia Influenza             West Nile Virus
```

I need to remove the repeats and blanks but keep the same data structure (I don't know what you would call this... 'concentrating' as opposed to 'aggregating' maybe?). So what I'd end up with is this:

```
      country  survey.1    survey.2        survey.3
1 Afghanistan Influenza Hepatitis C West Nile Virus
2   Australia Influenza             West Nile Virus
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does each column other than the country have only a single unique value?

Comment: Yes, for example survey.1 is always either "Influenza" or blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `plyr`:

```
ddply(df,.(country),
      function(x) 
        sapply(x,function(y){
          xx= unique(y[nchar(y)>0])
          ifelse(length(xx)>0,xx,unique(y))
        }
        )
)  

     country  survey.1    survey.2        survey.3
1 Afghanistan Influenza Hepatitis C West Nile Virus
2     Algeria                                      
3   Australia Influenza             West Nile Virus
```

Comment: @patabongo Ok. I change completely my answer.

Comment: Ah! plyr! I was trying to remember which package had ddply.